# is there some event like onEditorOpen?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

## what i want to do

i want to write a plugin which could open file(which code could not) use user configed cmd.

user config like

```
{
    'mp3':'c:/mp3player/mp3.exe {file_path}'
}
```

when i use code to open a mp3 the plugin will run this cmd

## what the problem

i could not fould a event triger me on each file open

## what i have know/try

vscode has some event like

1. workspaceContains:${toplevelfilename}
2. onLanguage:${language}

but all of this are hardcode in package.json and could not triger on all file type

### help me

it there some advise? maybe this is not a vscode plugin should do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach for that is to listen to the `didOpen` workspace event:

```
workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument((doc: TextDocument) => {
    if (doc.languageId == "mp3" && doc.uri.scheme === "file") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But note: vscode will not allow to open big or binary files. It will hence not activate your extension for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such an application by using VS Code's Custom Editor API.

It seems that there is already an extension to play audio files.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sukumo28.wav-preview